# How does Castle Windsor respond to a class which implements multiple interfaces?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

For example I have two interfaces: ICustomerService and IOrderService which each has a couple of functions like GetCustomer, GetOrder, etc.

I want one class to implement both interfaces: Server.

How does Castle Windsor respond to this?
Is it possible in the first place?
When I resolve the Server object based on one of the two interfaces, will I get the same object?
What happens when I have a constructor that has both interfaces in its parameters? Will there still be one object constructed.

assuming the LifeStyle is left to its default: Singleton.

Answer (score 4):

There's no hard one-to-one mapping between a CLR type and a Windsor service or component ([glossary if needed is here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md)).

So you can have any of the following scenarios:

- Many Components with different implementation types expose a single Service

  ```
  container.Register(
     Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>(),
     Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo2>()
  );
  ```
- Many Components with same implementation type expose a single Service

  ```
  container.Register(
     Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>(),
     Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>().Named("second")
  );
  ```
- Many Components with same implementation type expose different Services

  ```
  container.Register(
     Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>(),
     Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>().Named("second")
  );
  ```
- Single Component expose different Services

  ```
  container.Register(
     Component.For<IFoo, Bar>().ImplementedBy<Foo1>()
  );
  ```

As you can see, yes - it is possible, and whether or not you'll get the same instance (assuming singleton) depends on which option you chose - if both Services will be exposed by the same Component, or not.